How to Configure OAuth2 Authorization and Resource Servers in the Same Spring Boot 2.x Application?
I'm upgrading my Spring Boot application from version 1.5.3 to 2.0.x and I'm encountering issues with the OAuth2 Authorization Server configuration. In Spring Boot 1.5.3, I had both the Resource Server and Authorization Server configured in the same application using the following setup:
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore;

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthServerOAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    protected DynamicJdbcDao dynamicJdbcDao;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer
            .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
            .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dynamicJdbcDao.getCurrentDataSource());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
            .tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }
}


However, with Spring Boot 2.0.x, the OAuth2 Authorization Server has been moved to a separate module outside Spring Security, and I'm struggling to find resources that help me maintain both servers in the same application.
Dependencies
Spring Boot 1.5.4.RELEASE:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
</dependency>

Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
</dependency>

Can anyone provide guidance or examples on how to configure both the Authorization Server and Resource Server in the same Spring Boot 2.0.x application?

The dynamicJdbcDao is used to dynamically get the current data source for client details.
The client credentials are stored in oauth_client_details table.
I want to keep the configuration as similar as possible to the previous version to minimize changes.

